# Delegation: delegated method doesn't see outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, delegation

I have `two views` in the `Tab Bar View`. I want my `second` view to inform `first` view, when its Text Fields have changed value. I've done all the necessary coding for it, but there is one problem - `first` view doesn't see connected label outlets in the method declaration.

Code of the `second` view:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldHasChanged:(UITextField *)sender {

id<HPAAddCarOverallInfoTVCDelegate> strongDelegate = [[HPAAddCarMainViewController alloc] init];

if([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addCarOverallInfoVC:textFieldValueChanged:)]) {

    [strongDelegate addCarOverallInfoVC:self textFieldValueChanged:sender.text];
    }
}
```

Code of the `first` view:

```
-(void)addCarOverallInfoVC:(HPAAddCarOverallInfoTableViewController *)viewController textFieldValueChanged:(NSString *)value
{
self.overallVCFieldCount.text = value;
NSLog(@"%@", value);
}
```

`self.overallVCFieldCount.text = value;` - value exist, but textField doesn't.

As I think, problem belongs at this line of code:

```
id<HPAAddCarOverallInfoTVCDelegate> strongDelegate = [[HPAAddCarMainViewController alloc] init];
```

I guess, that delegate isn't exact view with which I am working with. Bouth views are loaded at the same time via storyboard. If I am correct with my thought, can you tell me please, how can I give a pointer to exact `first` view which as `second` view are loaded when Tab Bar View controller goes on the screen?

Comment: You have to assign "first view" into your delegate. Something like strongDelegate = firstViewController. Where and when depends on the place where you init "first view".

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new view controller in `textFieldHasChanged`. If you have that view controller in IB, instantiate it like this:

```
UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
id<HPAAddCarOverallInfoTVCDelegate> strongDelegate = st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

Where `identifier` is the identifier you have given your view controller in your storyboard.

Comment: Thank you, for your respond. This suggestion does trigger delegate method. But, unfortunately I have the same behaviour - I can't assign `value` to my textFields in the method declaration by any way, but can do that outside the method.